# Changing ever 4th pixel with a shader

Tags: xcode, opengl-es, sprite-kit, fragment-shader

I'm new to shaders and can't quite figure out why the mod() function is not working as I'd expect. I'm writing a shader for an SKScene in SpriteKit using Xcode.
I can change to whole screen red so I know that the shader is being applied to the scene.
Would be great if someone could take a look at the code below and help me out.

Thanks

```
vec2 xy = gl_FragCoord.xy;
vec4 colour = vec4(0.0 ,0.0 ,0.0 ,1.0);
float m = mod(xy.x, 3.0);

if (m == 0.0) {
    // never going here
    colour.r = 1.0;//turn it red
}

gl_FragColor = colour;
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting and how is it not working?

Comment: I expecting to see a black screen with red vertical lines every 3rd pixel. I would expect a value between 0 and 2 to be returned. The screen is always black. it seems that m never  equals zero.

Comment: Try changing your modulo expression to `float m = mod(xy.x, 4.0)` and your if-statement to `if (int(m) == 0) {`.

Comment: Thanks. That also worked.

Comment: You need to call floor() to snap the numeric value to an whole integer bound. Not doing that is keeping it from exactly matching the floating point 0.0. Just do "m = floor(mod(xy.x, 3.0));" and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the mod values to to integers worked.

```
highp int x = int(xy.x);
//float m = xy.x - 3.0 * floor(xy.x / 3.0);
highp int m = mod(xy.x, 3);
```

Comment: Are you sure this compiles? Also, it looks like you are changing every 3rd pixel.

Comment: That all worked. It was something to do with the mod function being a integer not a float. Yes that did change every 3rd pixel. Must have written 4th by mistake, but the principle is the same.